# selecting svg for performing action on D3 bar charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am relatively new to D3 and I am following the [tutorial here](http://bl.ocks.org/yuuniverse4444/8325617) to try to make a bar chart that responds to "mouseout", "click" and "mousein". I have already made the static bar chart work, but I have trouble figuring out how to select the bars in the bar chart, so that I could make them into a path and do something like this on it:

```
path.on('mouseover', function(d) {                            
  //Do something
  });
```

Right now if I create an svg associated with the bar chart, it simply creates a lot of `<rect>` objects with empty attributes. But I want the `<rect>` to refer to the `<div>` that is creating the bars.

This is my JS code:

```
 var dataset  = [
  {name:"A" , length:10},
  {name:"B" , length:20},
  {name:"C" , length:30}
  ]
  var lengthlist = [10,20,30]

  var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 120])
    .range([0, d3.max(lengthlist)]);

  d3.select(".chart")
    .selectAll("div")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter().append("div")
    .style("width", function(d) { return x(d.length)/d3.max(lengthlist) + "px"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });


  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  var path = svg.selectAll(".chart")
          .data(dataset)
          .enter()
          .append("rect");
  var path = svg.selectAll('div')
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('fill', function(d, i) { 
      return color(d.data.length);
    });
```

CSS code:

```
.chart div {
  font: 8px sans-serif;
  background-color: steelblue;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 10px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
  height:12px;
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear what are you trying to accomplish here `svg.selectAll('div')` and then later adding path...not clear

Comment: I'm not sure whether I'm doing it right but when I inspect the elements of a bar chart, each bar shows up as a div. That's why I thought I should selectAll('div') to grab onto the bar objects. That might be the wrong way of doing it.

Comment: I am sorry its definitely wrong. If you want to make a simple bar chart follow this example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304